# WPF Bind to sys:Boolean not updating

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to update a Resource Value every now and then, however the binding is not updating, how can I go about implementing the Notify method?

This is how I update the Resource, using a timer, the CheckInternet.Status returns a Boolean.

```
_timer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
            {
                if (t < 10)
                {
                    t++;
                }
                else
                {
                    Application.Current.Resources["InternetConnected"] = new CheckInternet().Status;
                    t = 0;
                }
                CurrentTime = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
            };
```

I'm assuming I need something like the following, however I don't really want to add an additional property to bind to, could I not just create an instance of NotifyBoolean and have it set and unset a value and Notify the update without needing an additional property?

```
public class NotifyBoolean : Common.NotifyUIBase
    {

    }
```

**Edit - The Binding**

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource InternetConnected}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToStringConverter}, StringFormat=Internet: {0}}" />
```

Comment: What does the binding look like? The one binding `InternetConnected` to something? You may be able to fix it by just using `DynamicResource` instead of `StaticResource`, depending on that binding.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Woops sorry forgot that, added it to post.

Comment: I know I didn't really answer your question, but I don't think what you're asking for is possible. The closest you can get is to manually invalidate the binding by calling `InvalidateProperty` on the dependency property `TextBlock.TextProperty` in your `timer.Tick` handler. You'll have to give your `TextBlock` a name first so you can call `textBlock.InvalidateProperty(TextBlock.TextProperty)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ResourceDictionary` doesn't have any events that are raised when a resource is changed, and generally speaking, you don't use resources for this purpose. Usually, resources are used for things you want to create once and share, like styles, or things like images, brushes, etc. I would even go so far as to say you generally don't want to put something in your `ResourceDictionary` that could change at some point.

#### Recommendation: use [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

WPF relies on two interfaces for change notification: for properties, you need to implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx). For collections, implement [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) (or more simply, just use an [`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx), which handles it all for you).

So you create a class:

```
public class CheckInternetModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool m_InternetConnected;
    public bool InternetConnected
    {
        get { return m_InternetConnected; }
        set
        {
            m_InternetConnected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

You can make this your control's `DataContext` and change your binding to `{Binding InternetConnected}`.

If you really want to use resources, you could add an instance of this class to your Resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <vm:CheckInternetModel x:Key="CheckInternetModel"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Your binding becomes...

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding InternetConnected Source={StaticResource CheckInternetModel}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToStringConverter}, StringFormat=Internet: {0}}" />
```

Your `timer.Tick`becomes...

```
((CheckInternetModel)Application.Current.Resources["CheckInternetModel"]).InternetConnected = new CheckInternet().Status;
```

#### Workaround: manually invalidate the binding

If you insist on storing this as a boolean in the resource dictionary, the only solution left is to manually invalidate the binding using [`DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.invalidateproperty(v=vs.110).aspx). So you'll have to give your `TextBlock` a name and then from within your `timer.Tick` handler, add:

```
textBlock.InvalidateProperty(TextBlock.TextProperty);
```

That's not enough though. Your binding is to a `StaticResource`, so it will not query the `ResourceDictionary` to get the resource again. You'll have to change the binding to:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={DynamicResource InternetConnected}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToStringConverter}, StringFormat=Internet: {0}}" />
```

A `DynamicResource` forces the binding to look up the resource again each time it's requested, so when you invalidate the `TextProperty`, it'll retrieve `InternetConnected` from the dictionary again and it'll have the new value.

Comment: If any of that is unclear, let me know and I'll expand on it.